# Pyomo's SolverFactory cannot create Ipopt (OSX) - possibly related to COIN-OR

Tags: python, macos, optimization, ipopt

I'm trying to use Pyomo to find the optimal values of a Python model on OSX. I got the script from https://github.com/shoibalc/recem, and  installed Pyomo and COIN-OR following the instructions to the extent that I could, changing a few things that were outdated or didn't seem to work on OSX.

The code that is causing problems is below.

```
import pyomo
from pyomo.opt.base import *
from pyomo.opt.parallel import SolverManagerFactory
from DICE2007 import createDICE2007
from DICEutils import DICE_results_writer

global start_time
start_time = time.time()

dice = createDICE2007()
dice.doc = 'OPTIMAL SCENARIO'
opt = SolverFactory('ipopt',solver_io='nl') 
tee = False
options =   """
        halt_on_ampl_error=yes"""
solver_manager = SolverManagerFactory('serial')

print '[%8.2f] create model %s OPTIMAL SCENARIO\n' %(time.time()-start_time,dice.name)

instance = dice.create()
print '[%8.2f] created instance\n' %(time.time()-start_time)

results = solver_manager.solve(instance, opt=opt, tee=tee, options=options, suffixes=['dual','rc'])
```

This crashes on the last ("results") line, with the following error message:

> The SolverFactory was unable to create the solver "ipopt"
>   and returned an UnknownSolver object.  This error is raised at the point 
>   where the UnknownSolver object was used as if it were valid (by calling 
>   method "solve").
>
> The original solver was created with the following parameters:
>       solver_io: nl
>       type: ipopt
>       _args: ()
>       options: {}
>       _options_str: []

I'm very new to all this, but thought that maybe Pyomo can't access the ipopt file it needs, which I think for me is located in the COIN-OR binaries I downloaded. I tried adding the relevant-seeming files to my PYTHONPATH and also importing them into the script, which didn't help. Any ideas what I should try next to either make this work, or to amend the script to something that would work?

Answer (score 1):

A colleague of mine had the same issue and he managed to solve it by generating the solver object with the route to the IPOPT AMPL executable:

```
opt = SolverFactory('/route/to/ipopt',solver_io='nl')
```